# Display Data in Django table where data has similarities betwen row and column

Tags: python, django, timetable

Currently i'm dealing with timetable project,  have a list of schedule saved in database and i want to print them in a table where a schedule should be placed on a right place based on row(days) and columns (timeslots).
i have tried to arrange schedule and it appear as follows:
[appearance of current tried schedule arrangement picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btskz.png)

The view used is as follows

```
def lecturerTimeTable(request):
lecname=Lecturer.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
context={
    'schedule': TeachingTimetable.objects.filter(lecturer=lecname).order_by('meet_time'),#get lecturer
    'program': Program.objects.all(),
    'days': MeetingTime.objects.all().values('day').distinct(), #day
    'slots': MeetingTime.objects.all().values('time').distinct(),#timeslot
    'url_name':'class',#for active link
    'lecturer':lecname,
    'StarterPage':'Class-Timetable'# for head 
}
return render(request,'users/class_timetable.html',context)
```

The template table is as follows

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="8"><center>{{lecturer}}</center</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            {% for time in slots  %}
                <th class="time">{{time.time}}</th>{% comment %} timeslot from 07:00-09:00 to 17:00-21:00 {% endcomment %}
                {% endfor %}
          
            </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for day in days %}
<tr>
    <th>{{day.day}} </th>
        {% for lesson in schedule %}
            {% if lesson.meet_day == day.day%}
            {% if lesson.meet_time == '13:00 - 15:00' %} 

            <td>{{lesson.course}} <br> 
                {{lesson.lecturer}}<br>
                {{lesson.venue}}<br>
                {{lesson.meet_day}} {{lesson.meet_time}}</td>
            
                {% comment %} {% endif %} {% endcomment %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So i appreciate i will get help soon!

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the output/result?

Comment: i have attached the results as an png image file on the question @Ghazi